# Modtraker module for Product Block?

Tags: php, vtiger

Is it possible to modtrack product block?  I want to mod track the changes of detail in item block. Any buddy have solution.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i install modtracker module vtiger 5.3.0 but it's not working in it.

Answer (score 2):

This is very difficult task and huge thing. I can say that you can do this but you have to find how. you have to set permission for those fields which are in product block. And have to set label for those and also you have to get old and new values to pass it for modtracking. if value doesnot match with old then insert it otherwise not.